# Get value from input type email with Angular

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-scope

How can I pass the value of an `<input type='email'>` using `angularjs`. I need to validate the email address on the input of my form and need to generate a key with this. The only thing I need to know is how should I get the value from the `input`.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('EmailController', function($scope) {
    $scope.hash = "";
    $scope.generateKey = function () {
      var resultKey = $scope.email;
      // TODO: generate key
      
      // Assing value to hash
      $scope.hash = resultKey;
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="EmailController">
  <form>
    <p>Email:&nbsp;<input type="email" ng-model="email" ng-keyup="generateKey()"></p>
    <p><b>Hash:&nbsp;</b>{{hash}}</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

#### Edit 1

I could use `<input type='text'>` and validate with a `regex` but I want to use `type='email'` as in the cellphone display more options on the keyboard. Does exist a way to get the `input` value using `angular` even if it isn't a valid email?

Comment: `$scope.email` should have the value of the input field.

Comment: Well, it doesn't @PrerakSola

Comment: You need to enter a valid email address. Here's a fiddle of your exact code. It works completely fine. https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/vh6vgxw8/

Comment: @PrerakSola, thanks but thats my issue. I added more information to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way angular handles input values and validations is via $parsers. you can intercept the default parsers and therefore get the value before it get to the email validation. Created this little snippet to further illustrate my point. Notice that I am not using .push to add my parser but instead I am using .unshift. I use unshift rather than push because I want to make sure my parser is the first on the list. or at least, the first at the moment i added to the list. This will guarantee that it runs before the default parsers which are already in the list by the time my code runs.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('EmailController', function($scope) {
      $scope.hash = "";
    });
    app.directive('generateKey', function(){
      return {
        require: ['ngModel'],
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrls){
          var ngModel = ctrls[0];

          ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(text){
            scope.hash = text;
            return text;
          });
        }
      };
  });
```

for a complete snippet, please visit: https://jsbin.com/vabofapigo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Be careful with this solution. It will write to whatever `hash` variable is in the current scope. So if you use this inside `ng-repeat` or `ng-if` it will break.

Comment: Yes! that is true. However, two things rise up from truth:
1. Why would you have duplicate variables attached to the scope?
2. if needed be, the directive scope can be isolated and have the hash variable passed down manually when adding the directive to the element.

Thoughts?

@FrankModica

Comment: 1. I'm saying that if you start out with only one `hash` on the controller scope, directives like `ng-if` create scopes that inherit from the parent scope (using `scope: true`). So your `generateKey` directive will initially read `hash` from the controller, but will write `hash` to its own scope (the one created by `ng-if`), creating a duplicate and breaking binding.
2. Yes, adding `scope: { hash: "=" }` to `generateKey` and passing in the `hash` is better: `<input ng-model="theEmail" generate-key hash="hash">`

Comment: Note that even doing #2 in the above comment may not work if `ng-if` is present, because in general you should bind to objects instead of primitives to prevent binding issues due to prototypal inheritance:  `<input ng-model="data.theEmail" generate-key hash="data.hash">`. This would not be an issue with your directive of course. It's just how binding works.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }"` if you want invalid email addresses to be bound to your controller:

```
<input type="email" ng-model="email" ng-keyup="generateKey()" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }">
```

**Edit:** You usually shouldn't data-bind to a primitive because prototypal inheritance can sometimes lead to binding to the wrong scope. Try binding to an object instead, like `data.email`.

**Edit:** [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/sh9hypzv/2)

Comment: Well, that doesn't changes the fact that when I start to wrtie something like: `fdsfds` I can't see the output.

Comment: You can't? I played around with the `jsfiddle` provided in the comments and added my solution and it works. Perhaps you have a problem data-binding to the wrong scope. Try binding to an object like `data.email` instead.

Comment: Paste the url here @Frank. I did and didn't workd, sorry for change `Accept Answer` without testing. When I tested rigth now it didn't work. Also I added more info to my question.

Comment: By the way, you may want to use `ng-change` instead of `ng-keyup`. It will run right after the model is updated.

Comment: add the link to your answer. If anoyone have the same problem can fix it, I don't understand why it didn't work when I  did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146688/discussion-between-xsami-and-frank-modica).